# Initial Rattle issues (Os) "Error: -with-x11" & "Error: gtk+ 2.24.32 did not build"

Tags: r, homebrew, rattle

I have been trying to install Rattle on my Os into my R using this instructions:
https://zhiyzuo.github.io/installation-rattle/

I get to Line 7 and input

```
~$ brew install --with-x11 cairo
```

and then get

```
Updating Homebrew...
Usage: brew install [options] formula|cask

Install a formula or cask. Additional options specific to a      formula may be
appended to the command.

Unless HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP is set, brew cleanup will then  be run for
the installed formulae or, every 30 days, for all formulae.
...

**Error: invalid option: --with-x11**'''
```

Ive tried to continue on installing Cairo without the "--with-x11" (as been suggested they no longer support that).
So I did just "brew install cairo" that worked.

I go to line 9 Now we can install gtk+ by:
~$ brew install --build-from-source --verbose gtk+

And I get:

```
**Error: gtk+ 2.24.32 did not build
Logs:
     /Library/Logs/Homebrew/gtk+/00.options.out
    /Library/Logs/Homebrew/gtk+/01.configure.cc
   /Library/Logs/Homebrew/gtk+/config.log
  /Library/Logs/Homebrew/gtk+/01.configure
READ THIS: https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting'''
```

If this helps in the last part I see in the terminal things saying:

```
==> ./configure --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-silent-rules -    -prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+/2.24.32_3 --disable-glibtest --enable-introspection=yes --with-gdktarget=x11 --enable-x11-backend
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --enable-x11-backend
```

and

```
configure: error: Package requirements (cairo-xlib >= 1.6) were not met:
```

No package 'cairo-xlib' found
Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables      CAIRO_BACKEND_CFLAGS
and CAIRO_BACKEND_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

Anyone have any suggestions for this ?

Thanks.